# Register router directives globally with angular router rc3

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

I do not want to register the Router_Directives for every component.

I want to do it globally as I did before:

```
import { RouterConfig ,Router, ActivatedRoute, ROUTE_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTE_PROVIDERS ]);
```

but ROUTE_PROVIDERS does not exist/exported in router module.

How can I do that with the RC3 router?

Comment: I assume you are trying to use the router 3.0.0-alpha7? - In which case I don't think ROUTE_PROVIDERS exists, but instead there is a provideRouter function that is intended to take it's place... of course it is still in alpha

Comment: yep, check out our options [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?apiFilter=router#stq=router&stp=1) and compare the router and router-depracated

Comment: yes as I wrote in the tags router3! That https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/provideRouter-function.html could work I try later.

Comment: I am bootstrapping the APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS via export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
  
]; that worked! even when I removed all directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] in each component.

Comment: NO, it does not work. I only worked because I did some wrong deployment. When I bootstrap the APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS and there is at least ONE component not having a set directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] then I get an error message that some router-outlet is missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we need is a [multi-provider](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html)

Here's what I did for some pipes that I created that I wanted to make globally available:

```
import {provide, PLATFORM_PIPES} from '@angular/core';
...
bootstrap(MegaDashboardAppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(PLATFORM_PIPES,
    {
      useValue: [
        Truthy,
        PrettifiedCamel,
        KeysPipe,
        IfDate
      ],
      multi: true
    }) // provide pipes globally
]);
```

I imagine you can do the same for any directives that you need globally available as well implemented as such:

```
import {provide, PLATFORM_PIPES, PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
...
bootstrap(Example, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  ...
  provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES,
    {
      useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
      multi: true
    }) 
]);
```

Just tested, Works wonderfully, especially with Angular material 2 directives as well :)